# Express.js : Interesting result

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm currently learning `Express JS` from the scratch. My goal is to become proficient with `Node` and `Express`.

While trying out some examples online, I ran into this interesting scenario. I'm building simple `http server`. The code is as follows.

```
var express = require("express");
var port = 8080;

var app = express();

app.get("*",function(req,res){
    res.end("Hello World!");
});

app.listen(port,function(){
    console.log("Listening on Port: %s",port);
});
```

If I run this by hitting `http://localhost:8080`, it outputs `Hello World!`. Perfect, Great.

Then I tried to pass some parameters through `URL` with this code

```
var express = require("express");
var port = 8080;

var app = express();

app.get("/name/:user_name",function(req,res){
    res.status(200);
    res.set('Content-type','text/html');
    res.end("<html><body><h1>Hello "+req.params.user_name+"!!!</h1></body></html>");
});

app.get("*",function(req,res){
    res.end("Hello World!");
});

app.listen(port,function(){
    console.log("Listening on Port: %s",port);
});
```

Then I run it by hitting `http://localhost/name/Maverick`, It outputs `Hello Maverick!!!`. Great, Perfect.

But here is the interesting part, when I switch the order of `app.get("*")` and `app.get("/name/:user_name")` the output changes.

For example, if I change `app.js` code to look like

```
var express = require("express");
var port = 8080;

var app = express();

app.get("*",function(req,res){ // <<<<--------- app.get("*") is first in this case
    res.end("Hello World!");
});

app.get("/name/:user_name",function(req,res){
    res.status(200);
    res.set('Content-type','text/html');
    res.end("<html><body><h1>Hello "+req.params.user_name+"!!!</h1></body></html>");
});

app.listen(port,function(){
    console.log("Listening on Port: %s",port);
});
```

And if I run it hitting `http://localhost:8080/name/Maverick` then it outputs `Hello World`.

The question is, does the order of `app.get()` routes matter?

Even when I have defined the route for `/name/:user_name` why it doesn't get called?

Is there any way to make the code independent of the order in which `app.get()` routes are defined?

Comment: If I replace `app.get("*")` with `app.get("/")` then it works fine. Whats going on here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The routes are ordered as you define them. The `"*"` route catches all urls right? So when express receives a url it itereates all routes and the first one which meets the criteria is being called. That is why your second route is not called. Usually the `"*"` route is left for last. This is also how ASP.NET MVC's routes work.

EDIT: The `"/"` route only catches the `http://url/` url unlike the other one.

Comment: Thank you for your precise explanation :). Later I realised that `app.get()` takes `Regular Expression` as a parameter. No wonder the `*` matches with everything.